# Cant add image and media files from database on production mode Django Cpanel

Tags: django, web, cpanel

i have a website based Django mysql and my problem is when i want to add mediafiles(images and etc) from database in django admin panel , idk why but its doesnt work and its doesn`t show me any error! just 10 second wait and after that it whows me this : This site can’t be reached im using Cpanel and my code in setting is :
for url :

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

setting :

```
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/samaliz1/public_html/media"
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/samaliz1/public_html/static"
```

and model:

```
prof_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/prof_pics", null=True, blank=True)
```

i should say that my staticfiles working perfectly but idk why my media doesnt i will be so thankfull if u guys help me <3